# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Worldbuilding's [second moderator election](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: JDługosz]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.com/results/6669260608765952/0).

Comment: There's a less pretty, but still functional report of the election available [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35584855#35584855).

Comment: Congrats man, good luck.

Comment: @randal'thor: Turns out OpaVote moved from .org to .com and the former certificate expired. From now on, I'll use the updated URL.

Comment: I removed the "featured" tag a little early to attempt to defeat [this bug](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4596/28) (which is becoming a real problem for our blog promotion).

Comment: And... didn't work.  Now we just get other meta questions in the community bulletin, but not our second scheduled event (on main; works on meta).  Sorry JDługosz for taking away a bit of your glow for nothing.

Answer (score 25):

Congratulations JDługosz on winning the election!

Comment: Also a big round of applauds for all nominees, you all made a good impression with your presentations.

Answer (score 3):

Well done JDługosz!

Also a nod to James and Michael who both did exceptionally. I'm blown away that I got any first votes, but nevertheless it's great to see so many people taking part in the voting process and giving their input.

Long live WorldBuilding!